# extract text from strong tag

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the information of exterior color, interior color, transmission respectively from cars.com.

HTML:

```
<ul class="listing-row__meta">
 <li>
  <strong>
    Ext. Color:
  </strong>
    Gray
 </li>
 <li>
  <strong>
    Int. Color:
  </strong>
    White
 </li>
 <li>
  <strong>
    Transmission:
  </strong>
    Automatic
 </li>
```

I tried the following code, but it showed 'expected string or bytes-like object'. Any recommendations or solutions will be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

url ='https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

all_matches = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'shop-srp-listings__listing-container'})

for each in all_matches:

    info=each.findAll('ul',class_='listing-row__meta')
    pattern=re.compile(r'Ext. Color:')
    matches=pattern.finditer(info)
    for match in matches:
        print(match.text)
```

Comment: Use a DOM parser, not regex https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this would be a bit closer to what you might be trying to extract, I guess, with an expression similar to:

```
(?is)<strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<\/strong>
```

or,

```
(?is)(?<=<strong>)\s*[^<]*?\s*(?=<\/strong>)
```

Pretty sure, you can do that with `bs4` built-in functions too.

#### Test 1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

all_matches = soup.find_all(
    'div', {'class': 'shop-srp-listings__listing-container'})

for each in all_matches:
    info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')
    matches = re.findall(
        r'(?is)<strong>\s*[^<]*?\s*<\/strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<', str(info[0]))
    for match in matches:
        print(match)
```

#### Output 1

```
Gray
Beige
Automatic
AWD
Gray
White
Automatic
AWD
Black
```

---

#### Test 2

You can also make a dict out of that, if you like, by a bit modification:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

all_matches = soup.find_all(
    'div', {'class': 'shop-srp-listings__listing-container'})

for each in all_matches:
    info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')
    matches = dict(re.findall(
        r'(?is)<strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<\/strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<', str(info[0])))

    for k, v in matches.items():
        print(f'{k} {v}')
```

#### Output 2

```
Ext. Color: Gray
Int. Color: Beige
Transmission: Automatic
Drivetrain: AWD
Ext. Color: Gray
Int. Color: White
Transmission: Automatic
Drivetrain: AWD
Ext. Color: Black
```

#### Test 3

If you'd rather lists:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

all_matches = soup.find_all(
    'div', {'class': 'shop-srp-listings__listing-container'})

for each in all_matches:
    info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')
    matches = re.findall(
        r'(?is)<strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<\/strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<', str(info[0]))

    for match in matches:
        print(list(match))
```

#### Output

```
['Transmission:', 'Automatic']
['Drivetrain:', 'RWD']
['Ext. Color:', 'Gray']
['Int. Color:', 'Gray']
['Transmission:', 'Automatic']
['Drivetrain:', 'RWD']
['Ext. Color:', 'White']
['Int. Color:', 'Black']
['Transmission:', 'Automatic']
['Drivetrain:', 'RWD']
['Ext. Color:', 'White']
['Int. Color:', 'Beige']
['Transmission:', 'Automatic']
['Drivetrain:', 'AWD']
['Ext. Color:', 'Gray']
['Int. Color:', 'Beige']
['Transmission:', 'Automatic']
['Drivetrain:', 'AWD']
['Ext. Color:', 'White']
```

#### Test 4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

all_matches = soup.find_all(
    'div', {'class': 'shop-srp-listings__listing-container'})


keys = ['Ext. Color', 'Int. Color', 'Transmission', 'Drivetrain']

outputs = dict()

for each in all_matches:
    info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')
    matches = dict(re.findall(
        r'(?is)<strong>\s*([^<:]*?)\s*:\s*<\/strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<', str(info[0])))

    for item in matches.items():
        if item[0] not in outputs:
            outputs[item[0]] = [item[1]]
        if item[0] in keys:
            outputs[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

#### Output 4

> {'Ext. Color': ['Silver', 'Silver', 'White', 'White', 'Black', 'Gray',
>   'Gray', 'Black', 'Black', 'White', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Silver', 'Gray',
>   'Black', 'White', 'Black', 'Gray', 'White', 'Black', 'Black'], 'Int.
>   Color': ['Beige', 'Beige', 'Black', 'White', 'Black', 'Black', 'Gray',
>   'Beige', 'Black', 'Black', 'Beige', 'Beige', 'Black', 'Black',
>   'Black', 'Black', 'Black', 'Black', 'White', 'White', 'Black'],
>   'Transmission': ['Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic'], 'Drivetrain': ['AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD',
>   'RWD', 'RWD', 'RWD', 'RWD', 'AWD', 'RWD', 'RWD', 'RWD', 'AWD', 'RWD',
>   'RWD', 'AWD', 'RWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD']}

#### Test 5

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

all_matches = soup.find_all(
    'div', {'class': 'shop-srp-listings__listing-container'})


keys = ['Ext. Color', 'Int. Color', 'Transmission', 'Drivetrain']

outputs = dict()

for each in all_matches:
    info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')
    matches = dict(re.findall(
        r'(?is)<strong>\s*([^<:]*?)\s*:\s*<\/strong>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<', str(info[0])))

    for item in matches.items():
        if item[0] not in outputs:
            outputs[item[0]] = [item[1]]
        if item[0] in keys:
            outputs[item[0]].append(item[1])


print(outputs)

print('*' * 50)

no_duplicate_outputs = dict()
for item in outputs.items():
    if item[0] not in no_duplicate_outputs:
        no_duplicate_outputs[item[0]] = list(set(item[1]))

print(no_duplicate_outputs)
```

#### Output 5

> {'Ext. Color': ['Black', 'Black', 'White', 'Black', 'Other', 'Gray',
>   'White', 'White', 'Gray', 'White', 'Gray', 'Silver', 'Blue', 'Black',
>   'Silver', 'Silver', 'Black', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Black', 'White'], 'Int.
>   Color': ['Black', 'Black', 'Beige', 'Beige', 'Black', 'Gray', 'Black',
>   'Beige', 'Beige', 'White', 'Black', 'Black', 'Gray', 'Black', 'Black',
>   'Gray', 'Black', 'Black', 'Black', 'White', 'Black'], 'Transmission':
>   ['Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic', 'Automatic',
>   'Automatic'], 'Drivetrain': ['AWD', 'AWD', 'RWD', 'RWD', 'RWD', 'RWD',
>   'RWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'RWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD',
>   'RWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD', 'AWD']}
>   ************************************************** {'Ext. Color': ['Silver', 'White', 'Blue', 'Other', 'Black', 'Gray'], 'Int. Color':
>   ['Beige', 'White', 'Black', 'Gray'], 'Transmission': ['Automatic'],
>   'Drivetrain': ['RWD', 'AWD']}

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sRUGrK/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/sRUGrK/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to also get the text after the semicolon ( ex. Ext. Color: Gray)

Comment: I would like to put exterior color, interior color, transmission, drivetrain separately in in a list by creating exterior_color=[ ], interior color=[ ], transmission=[ ], drivetrain=[ ]. Any suggestions of how I could extract those information from the match? Thank you

Comment: Yes, this was what I was trying to get. Thank you. But there should only be 20 records for each item. The first record for each item is repeated. For instance, it should be like {'Ext. Color':['Silver', 'White', 'White', 'Black', .....]} instead of two silver {'Ext. Color':['Silver', 'Silver','White', 'White', 'Black', .....]}. How could this be fixed

Comment: I meant there should only be 20 values in the list of ext.color because there is only 20 cars in the website which we are scraping. Nevertheless, there are 21 values in the output for ext.color which you shown above in output 4.

Answer (score 1):

The Regex library's [`findAll` function returns a List of results](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall); so `info` is an array of strings, rather than a single string. You may need to iterate over each item in `info`, as well.

These objects return `bs4.Tag` objects (not strings), which can be cast to a string so they fit the `finditer` API. **(This is particularly confusing because bs4 renders them as though they were strings when you print the object `info`!)**

```py
for each in all_matches:
    info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')
    for item in info:
        pattern = re.compile(r'Ext. Color:')
        matches = pattern.finditer(str(item))
        for match in matches:
            print(match.text)
```

In this example, it's possible that `info` will be a List of length = 1; in this case, if you're sure you only want the first result, and that there will only be one result, you can convert to a call that returns a single occurrence, or simply use the first result with this line:

```py
info = each.findAll('ul', class_='listing-row__meta')[0]
```

and then use your code from the question as-is.

Comment: The code you provided still shows 'expected string or bytes-like object'

Comment: Sorry about that! Post the second-most-up-to-date version of my soln. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

The error your getting can be fixed by typecasting to str:

```
    matches=pattern.finditer(info)
```

change to:

```
    matches=pattern.finditer(str(info))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need for regex here. The html is regular and with bs4 4.7.1 + you can use :contains to target appropriate elements by their text and then next_sibling to get adjacent node containing value. Grab the lists, zip and convert to dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = ['Make','Ext','Int','Trans','Drive']
r = requests.get('https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?zc=92617&rd=10&stkTypId=28881&mkId=28263&searchSource=RESEARCH_SHOP_INDEX')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
make = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.listing-row__title')]
ext_color = [i.next_sibling.strip() for i in soup.select('strong:contains("Ext. Color:")')]
int_color = [i.next_sibling.strip() for i in soup.select('strong:contains("Int. Color:")')]
transmission = [i.next_sibling.strip() for i in soup.select('strong:contains("Transmission:")')]
drive = [i.next_sibling.strip() for i in soup.select('strong:contains("Drivetrain:")')]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(make, ext_color, int_color, transmission, drive), columns = headers)
print(df)
```